# Android two-way databinding with custom binding logic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-databinding

I use android data binding lib and I have a layout with checkboxes and I need to use custom checking logic ([layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s3Lq.png)).

Is there a way to create such a binding that checking one of the boxes causes the rest of them to uncheck? What would be the best approach?

Comment: For people that will say I should use radio buttons - this is not acceptable solution since I want to be able to reorder them easily and radio group does not allow that. The drawable could be different, sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

1. Have a common `OnClickListener` for the checkboxes
2. Assign the listener by XML (not necessary, but obviously better)
3. Loop through the checkboxes every time one is checked, and uncheck the others.

---

XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option 1"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Option 2"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

---

Activity

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View clickedView)
{
        LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        for (int i=0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view;
                if (checkbox.isChecked() && !checkbox.equals(clickedView)) {
                    checkbox.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

You can obviously create a custom `ViewGroup` called *CheckBoxGroup*, which receives the checkboxes and automatically implements this flow. But I don't think it's necessary, it will complicate things. And also won't be so flexible, since the checkboxes have to be all within it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Question used data-binding in a couple of places for very important reason: I'm only interested in solution that uses android data binding. All other solutions (while technically correct) will not solve my problem of handling this case automatically using databinding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: You don't need to access the direct parent in order to use my solution. Anyway, I understand that you want databinding, but I warn you that the code won't be clean. You still need to manually uncheck the other checkboxes and then bind the property "android:checked" with a boolean, for each checkbox. That's the solution I see...

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are normally used separately with each checkbox having a separate click listener registered to it. The Android Guidelines states the same. You can see that at : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html.

However, if you have a scenario where you need to use them, you'll have to create a logic using to do handle it yourself. Checkbox has a method **setChecked(boolean)** which can be used to set the state: true if you want it to be checked, false for unchecked state.

You can attach a listener to check the change is the check.

checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Attach separate listeners to each checkbox. When the check status of one changes make the appropriate changes to other checkboxes.

checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       if(isChecked) {
            checkbox2.setChecked(false);
            checkbox3.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            checkbox1.setChecked(false);
            checkbox3.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

checkbox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            checkbox1.setChecked(false);
            checkbox2.setChecked(false);
        }

    }
});
```

If you need the user to be able to select only one of the options you can use radiobuttons and use a radiogroup.

Radio Group: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. Question used data-binding in a couple of places for very important reason: I'm only interested in solution that uses android data binding. All other solutions (while technically correct) will not solve my problem of handling this case automatically using databinding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try.

1. Wrap all checkboxes in one Layout.
2. Create custom `static` method and pass `checkbox` with its value and parent layout in which you have all checkboxes.

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <import type="com.example.Bindings" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->Bindings.setCheckbox(chk1,linearParent)}"
            android:text="1" />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->Bindings.setCheckbox(chk2,linearParent)}"
            android:text="2" />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->Bindings.setCheckbox(chk3,linearParent)}"
            android:text="3" />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chk4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->Bindings.setCheckbox(chk4,linearParent)}"
            android:text="4" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is your custom method

```
public static void setCheckbox(CheckBox checkBox, LinearLayout parentLayout) {
    for (int i = 0; i < parentLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (parentLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {
            CheckBox child = (CheckBox) parentLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getId() != checkBox.getId())
                child.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

That's it, you are done with your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ObservableBoolean` for this. As a binding you would just set it  with `android:checked="@={observableBoolean}"`. With the two-way data binding `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` doesn't work anymore, but you already have the values in your view models now.

Now you only need to create your own radio group. This can be achieved easily with an [`Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback.html) you `addOnPropertyChangedCallback()` to all the `ObservableBoolean` you use for your checkboxes.

```
new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
    private ObservableBoolean observable = new ObservableBoolean();
    public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
        ObservableBoolean observable = (ObservableBoolean) sender;
        if (observable.get()) {
            this.observable.set(false);
            this.observable = observable;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do such a similar task i did the following:

- created an unique ViewModel that is added in the data field of xml

  ```
  <import type="android.view.View"/>
  <variable
      name="viewModel"
      type="compackagename.MyViewModel" />
  ```
- in xml binding notice the @={...} which is called a two way binding (updating the variable from the two way binding automatically updates the xml)

  ```
          <CheckBox
          android:checked="@={viewModel.checked1}"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <CheckBox
          android:checked="@={viewModel.checked2}"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  ```
- added ObservableBoolean fields to each checkBox in MyViewModel

  ```
  public final ObservableBoolean checked1 = new ObservableBoolean();
  ```
- in MyViewModel constructor

  ```
  checked1.set(false);
  checked2.set(false);

  checked1.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPropertyChanged(Observable observable, int i) {
          if (checked1.get()){
              checked2.set(false);
          }
      }
  });
  checked2.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onPropertyChanged(Observable observable, int i) {
          if (checked2.get()){
              checked1.set(false);
          }
      }
  });
  ```

You can optimise this by adding the ObservableBooleans in a list but the above is a good starting point that works.